# Get all images name from folder using link in controller for JSON response laravel 5.1

Tags: php, json, image, laravel, directory

Database have link of folder and folder contain many images. I want to get all images name but glob() (function) is not working..

```
function index($data){
        $users = DB::select('select * from `title` INNER JOIN `title_img` on `title`.title_no = `title_img`.title_no AND `title`.title_name = ?', [$data]);
        $ab = array();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $name = $user->img_folder;
            $nam = 'http://127.0.0.1/shaadi/public/data/'.$name;
            $ab[] = glob($name);
        }
    var_dump($ab);
    var_dump($nam);
        return response()->json($users);
    }
```

output

```
   <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=3)</i>
  0 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
      <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
  1 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
      <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
  2 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> 
    <b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
      <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'http://127.0.0.1/shaadi/public/data/image/caterer/standard/'</font> <i>(length=59)</i>
</pre>[{"title_no":1,"title_name":"Catering","title_description":"Let your taste buds loose!<br\/>We promise delicious high quality and hygienic delicious for you.","img_folder":"image\/caterer\/luxury\/"},{"title_no":1,"title_name":"Catering","title_description":"Let your taste buds loose!<br\/>We promise delicious high quality and hygienic delicious for you.","img_folder":"image\/caterer\/premium\/"},{"title_no":1,"title_name":"Catering","title_description":"Let your taste buds loose!<br\/>We promise delicious high quality and hygienic delicious for you.","img_folder":"image\/caterer\/standard\/"}]
```

Comment: Where is the `img_folder` located on your file system? Also your using Laravel embrace it by making use of the functionality it makes avaliable to you see https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem

Comment: img_folder is the column in the data base. Where the link " image/caterer/luxury/ " is written ..... and this image folder is it public/data/image/caterer....

Comment: $nam = 'http://127.0.0.1/shaadi/public/data/image/caterer/standard/ ;
$ab[] = Storage::allFiles($nam);

I need all the files in the **$nam** path

Comment: There a big difference if your trying to use your `$nam` variable as the paramter for getting the files compared with `$name` in your `glob` example. If your trying to pull a list of images from the URL thats a completely different matter and not what `glob` or `Storage::allFiles` will do.

Comment: actually i have written wrong in the example ... That's  glob($nam);

Comment: OK you need to step back and think about what your doing. There is a big difference in the URL path and the file system path. You want to be working with the file system path which is something like `/path/to/laravel/public/data/image/caterer/standard' if you use the Laravel filesystem stuff correctly this will help you.

Comment: i m using the path.... www.memorableshaadi.com/public/data/image/caterer/standard/Image1.jpg

Comment: in (standard) folder there are many images in this folder.... and i want all the images... but i don't know how many images are available i this....

Comment: so i m using glob function .....  but it is returning the empty array :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this to

```
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $name = $user->img_folder;
        $nam = 'http://127.0.0.1/shaadi/public/data/'.$name;
        $ab[] = glob($name);
    }
```

this

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $name = $user->img_folder;
    $nam = public_path('data/' . $name . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*');//getting real path
    $ab[] = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::glob($nam);//Matching all files
}
```

> But remember this will only get contents of a directory not
>   **`recursively`**.

To get the URL path you have to `str_replace` the paths like

```
str_replace(public_path(), '', $path)
```

& also you should apply the `asset` function

```
asset(str_replace(public_path(), '', $path))
```

Now if you are returning `$ab` variable which contains all the paths in a multidimensional array then you can either loop through or create a recursive function to achieve this or you can do it when setting value in `$ab` like this

```
$ab[] = collect(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::glob($nam))->map(function ($path)//this will convert array to laravel collection
        {
            return asset(str_replace(public_path(), '', $path));//converts to url
        })->filter(function ($path)
        {
            return $path;//removes any empty value
        })->values()//converts to values
        ->toArray();//converts to to array
```

This is a modified sample code from my project which worked for me although I didn't tested for your purpose but it should work.

Comment: @SachinMarwha I have edited my answer you can check it.